# JavaScript: add alert message if name or password less than 6

Tags: javascript

try to add function in JS where alert box will show message Password or Username must be more than 6 :

**Password :**

> Password must have atleast 6 characters

**Username :**

> Username must have atleast 6 characters

So far I got function show alert if Pass or Username is *NULL*

JaveScript Code :

```
    function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["namapengguna"].value;
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    alert("Nama must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    alert("User must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    alert("Pass must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["confirm_password"].value;
  if (x == "" || x == null) {
    alert("Confirm Pass must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
  else { 
        alert('Application Has Been Registered');
        location.assign("homeA.php");
        }
}
```

but I couldn't figure out how can add alert message if name or password less than 6.

Any idea or solution are really appreatiate.

p/s: *if my question is not good enough for you to understand, please tell me so I can improve it.*

Comment: Using `alert()` is probably the worst way to present this information, and popping this many is bordering on actively hostile to the user. Why not show a `<div>` near the input field that has the problem? This is a whole ton of code here that could be reduced by using jQuery and/or simple techniques like `const f = document.forms.myForm` to cut down on the ridiculous levels of duplication in it.

Comment: `<input ... minlength="6" />` job done, no JS needed.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the Idea, will keep it in mind. Already have an answer. TQ

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks for the Idea, will keep it in mind. Already have an answer. TQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check string length by doing `x.length`. So:

```
if (x.length <= 6) {
    // Do what you want
}
```

You may also want to make sure the user hasn't inputted any spaces at the start or end of the field.